# Configuration PHPcs in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, phpcs

I have copy paste the default phpcs.sublime-settings to User and set phpcs_execute_on_save to true but it does not work.
it shows me an error

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "./python3.3/threading.py", line 858, in run
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 488, in run
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 149, in get_errors
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 231, in execute
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 234, in parse_report
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 176, in shell_out
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What I am doing wrong for installing and configuration PHPcs?

This is configuration File

```
{
// Plugin settings

// Turn the debug output on/off
"show_debug": false,

// Which file types (file extensions), do you want the plugin to
// execute for
"extensions_to_execute": ["php"],

// Do we need to blacklist any sub extensions from extensions_to_execute
// An example would be ["twig.php"]
"extensions_to_blacklist": [],

// Execute the sniffer on file save
"phpcs_execute_on_save": true,

// Show the error list after save.
"phpcs_show_errors_on_save": true,

// Show the errors in the gutter
"phpcs_show_gutter_marks": true,

// Show outline for errors
"phpcs_outline_for_errors": true,

// Show the errors in the status bar
"phpcs_show_errors_in_status": true,

// Show the errors in the quick panel so you can then goto line
"phpcs_show_quick_panel": true,

// The path to the php executable.
// Needed for windows, or anyone who doesn't/can't make phars
// executable. Avoid setting this if at all possible
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "",

// Options include:
// - Sniffer
// - Fixer
// - Mess Detector
//
// This will prepend the application with the path to php
// Needed for windows, or anyone who doesn't/can't make phars
// executable. Avoid setting this if at all possible
"phpcs_commands_to_php_prefix": [],

// What color to stylise the icon
// https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View
// add_regsions
"phpcs_icon_scope_color": "comment",


// PHP_CodeSniffer settings

// Do you want to run the phpcs checker?
"phpcs_sniffer_run": true,

// Execute the sniffer on file save
"phpcs_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the phpcs application
// If empty, then use PATH version of phpcs, else use the set value
"phpcs_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "--standard": "PEAR",
//     "-n"
// }
"phpcs_additional_args": {
    "--standard": "PSR2",
    "-n": ""
},



// PHP-CS-Fixer settings

// Fix the issues on save
"php_cs_fixer_on_save": false,

// Show the quick panel
"php_cs_fixer_show_quick_panel": false,

// Path to where you have the php-cs-fixer installed
"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
"php_cs_fixer_additional_args": {

},



// phpcbf settings

// Fix the issues on save
"phpcbf_on_save": false,

// Show the quick panel
"phpcbf_show_quick_panel": false,

// Path to where you have the phpcbf installed
"phpcbf_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "--level": "all"
// }
"phpcbf_additional_args": {
    "--standard": "PSR2",
    "-n": ""
},



// PHP Linter settings

// Are we going to run php -l over the file?
"phpcs_linter_run": true,

// Execute the linter on file save
"phpcs_linter_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the php application
// If empty, then use PATH version of php, else use the set value
"phpcs_php_path": "",

// What is the regex for the linter? Has to provide a named match for 'message' and 'line'
"phpcs_linter_regex": "(?P<message>.*) on line (?P<line>\\d+)",



// PHP Mess Detector settings

// Execute phpmd
"phpmd_run": false,

// Execute the phpmd on file save
"phpmd_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the phpmd application
// If empty, then use PATH version of phpmd, else use the set value
"phpmd_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "codesize,unusedcode"
// }
"phpmd_additional_args": {
    "codesize,unusedcode,naming": ""
},


// PHP Scheck settings

// Execute scheck
"scheck_run": false,

// Execute the scheck on file save
"scheck_command_on_save": false,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the scheck application
// If empty, then use PATH version of scheck, else use the set value
"scheck_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
//Example:
//{
//  "-php_stdlib" : "/path/to/pfff",
//  "-strict" : ""
//}
"scheck_additional_args": {
    "-strict" : ""
}
```

}

Comment: is the `phpcs` executable on your PATH? if not, you should set `phpcs_executable_path` appropriately in your `phpcs.sublime-settings` file

Comment: there is not any string with "phpcs_executable_path" in configuration default file

Comment: Thanks it solved @KeithHall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have add the phpcs_executable_path right and change the User setting for this package